# На windows float выводится с запятой, а на linux с точкой. Как исправить?

Tags: php

Выполняю такой код на локалке (у меня windows и open server)

```
echo ' ' . 3.14;
```

Мне выводится

```
 3,14
```

Выполняю на боевом (на хостинге beget), мне выводится:

```
 3.14
```

Мне нужно, чтобы на локалке тоже выводилась точка. Как мне это сделать? Я думал, что проблема в локали. Я пробовал установить локаль перед выводом, это не помогло. Вот код:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en');
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
echo ' ' . 3.14;
```

Вот, что выводится:

```
en 3,14
```

То есть все равно через запятую.

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы выводилось с точкой? Кроме изменения настроек Windows.

Comment: Используйте [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php)("%7.2f", 3.14) и устанавливайте формат, нужный вам.

Comment: Можно еще number_format использовать https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Comment: Вообще, формат зависит от опции intl.default_locale из php.ini. Тут можно подробнее почитать https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intl.configuration.php